# Was 142386 closed because it's about FreeBSD, or because it might not also be about Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, scope, vote-to-close

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142386/how-to-modify-a-freebsd-9-0-iso-file) was closed as off topic, and there is a comment (though not by one of the close-voters) saying that it's off-topic but would be on topic at Unix.SE.

The question is undeniably about FreeBSD, in that it's asking how to remaster a FreeBSD ISO. But presumably, it's on topic for our site--after all, it's presumably about **how to do it using Ubuntu.** Furthermore, the specific information being requested doesn't seem to be particular to FreeBSD at all. This is asking how to remaster a bootable `.iso` image.

Is the reason this was closed **the assumption that the OP is not using Ubuntu**? If so, why was this assumption made without asking in a comment? Or did the OP communicate with someone via other means (e.g., chat), indicating that he is not actually using Ubuntu?

If someone asks how to create a text document, or edit images, or access email, and they don't explicitly state they're using Ubuntu, we assume they are, or we ask if we're unsure. But for some other questions, involving another operating system, we seem to assume they are not running Ubuntu. (That is, if I'm recalling correctly, this doesn't seem like an isolated case.) Is there a good reason to assume that? Or is this just a mistake that's made frequently?

Comment: Why do we help Windows users reinstall Windows without even using Ubuntu in any way than to slow down the user by creating partitions that must be deleted by the Windows installer, while we close a question that at least involves using Ubuntu to at least remaster the disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my capacity of supporting the other three members of the community, I was content that this was not a borderline case and that it was a potential better fit with Unix & Linux.

If the OP flagged for the migration I would have approached the mods there to migrate.

In this case, a junior member of the community dropped an "off-topic" comment.

Two senior members of the community supported this by exercising their close votes.  There wasnt any need to add additional comments.

FreeBSD I would contend is not an OS the majority of Ubuntonians are familiar with.  This sort of question would need feedback from the OP to resolve.  Hence, the combination of a non-ubuntu OS, the fact that he was using a third-party piece of software that may or may not be running on Ubuntu and that this may need further feedback led me to believe this is either off-topic or too-localised.

I dont believe this would have added to our mission to produce "reusable articles" for  ubuntu users.

As always, all closed questions can be reopened at any time.  If the OP in question flags or drops a comment to that, we can revisit this then.